# Jquery hover panel containing a form

Tags: jquery

I have this page, on which there's a side panel that expands on mouse over. On mouse out, it closes back. This was done using jquery's hover() function. In the panel however, is a form. Once i move my mouse into a text field in that form, the mouse out event activates and closes the panel with the form before i can do anything.
Can someone provide a way to prevent this? thanks.

Comment: I recomend not doing this. It can be a very frustrating user experience. Look at the twitter logon form for a good alternate. Click to expand, click off to retract.

Comment: I agree with you man. It's frustrating, Imagine trying to feel a form and your hand touches the touch pad or your mouse and the form just closes. I simply shelved the idea and used Click to open then used a "close icon" to close the panel. You gave good advice. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) events instead.

Comment: Only that it did not work in chrome 9.0.2 which was the browser i was using to test. must have been a bug. Tried the hover with firefox 3.6, opera 11 even I.E 8 and it worked. Anyways based on the comment i made above i've since scrapped the idea. It could be frustrating for the user. Thanks all. Appreciate it.